# ターミナルコマンド ファイル名の末尾に一定の文字列を加える

Tags: unix

macです。

あるディレクトリの中身が以下のようになってます。

1_X.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
4_X.jpg
5.jpg
.
.
.

ファイル名は常に"***.jpg"か、"***_X.jpg"になってます。
これを全て***_X.jpgにしたいです。
つまり"_X"がついてない全てのファイル名に"_X"を付与してあげたいです。

どのようにすればいいでしょうか。

Comment: お使いのシェルが bash で version 4 以降であれば `extglob` を使う方法があります。具体的には `shopt -s extglob` として、`for f in !(*_X.jpg);do mv "$f" "${f%.jpg}_X.jpg";done` とします。

Comment: こちらでうまくできました。ありがとうございます...。

Answer (score 1):

`find`で該当するファイルを探してリネームすることもできます。

```
find . ! -name *_X.jpg -type f -execdir sh -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.jpg}_X.jpg"' _ {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

こんな`shellscript`はいかがでしょうか？

```
#!/bin/sh

while [ -n "$1" ]
do
    fullname=$1
    extension=${fullname##*.}
    filename=${fullname%.*}
    suffix=${filename##*_}
    if [ "$suffix" != "X" ] ; then
        mv ${filename}"."${extension} ${filename}"_X."${extension}
    fi
    shift
done
```

コメントにある@metropolisさんの回答でも充分かも知れませんが、
上記をファイルに保存し、試しにjpegファイルとおなじディレクトリーに保存して、`chmod +x 755 ファイル名`というコマンドを実行した後、`./ファイル名 *.jpg`としてみてください。期待の結果が得られると思います。

実行が確認出来ましたら、`Terminal`から、

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
sudo cp ファイル名 /usr/local/bin
```

と、2つのコマンドを実行し、システムを汚さない実行ファイル起き場にコマンドを移動します。
あとは、お使いのshellがbashでしたら（通常はこのシェルが使われています）`お好みのエディター ~/.bashrc`で

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

という行を探し、なければ追加して下さい。
これで、次に`Terminal`を開いたら、どのディレクトリーからでも`ファイル名 *.jpg`でjpegファイルの末尾に`_X`が付いていなければ`_x`を追加するコマンドを実行出来ます。

`while [ -n "$1" ]`から`done`直前の行で`shift`すると、
引数を順次処理してくれ、応用が利くので憶えておいて損はないと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。 うまくできませんでした...。cdでディレクトリに移動して上記コードをEnterで実行してみたのですが...(T_T)

Comment: ＠nichikaさん、上記をjpegファイルとおなじディレクトリに保存して、chmod 755 `ファイル名`としてから、`.ファイル名 *.jpg`としてみてください。動く様なら、このファイルを`/usr/local/bin/`に置いてパスを通すとどこからでもこのシェルスクリプトを実行できるようになります